# collection.Searching does not add search() to views, etc

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

I have a few problems with collection.Searching.  It doesn't seem to work on views and ranges at least.  Shouldn't it?

The last two lines from the console below show things that I thought would work on Scala 2.11.2

```
> import collection.Searching._

> Seq( 1, 3 ) search 2
res0: collection.Searching.SearchResult = InsertionPoint(1)

> Seq( 1, 3 ).view search 2
error: value search is not a member of scala.collection.SeqView[Int,Seq[Int]]

> 0 to 10 search 5
error: value search is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive
```

Presumably, this is doe to not having an implicit IsSeqLike for those types.  Is there a reason there isn't one, or am I doing something wrong?